# Cakephp 2.4.1, using CakeDS Search plugin Array to string conversion,searching between dates

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I trying to search between dates using the `CakeDc` plugin. I am trying to use 2 separate form fields in the form/view, 1 for start date and the other for end date.

I need to have a single array so I can use the function `CreationDateRangeCondition` in the controller (unless this can be sorted somehow in the controller function) but I don't know how to do this. I am trying to learn `PHP` and `Cakephp`

**Controller:**

```
public $presetVars = array(

    array('creationDateBetween' => 'created', 'type' => 'value'),

);
public function index() {
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => $this->Post->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs));
    $this->set('posts', $this->paginate());
}
```

**Model:**
public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');

```
        public $filterArgs = array(

              'creationDateBetween'       => array(
            'type'      => 'expression',
            'method'    => 'CreationDateRangeCondition',
            'field'     => 'Post.created BETWEEN ? AND ?',
        ),
         );


public function CreationDateRangeCondition($data = array()){
    if(strpos($data['creationDateBetween'], ' - ') !== false){
        $tmp = explode(' - ', $data['creationDateBetween']);
        $tmp[0] = $tmp[0]."-01-01";
        $tmp[1] = $tmp[1]."-12-31";
        return $tmp;
    }else{
        return array($data['creationDateBetween']."-01-01", $data['creationDateBetween']."-12-31");
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
  <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('Post', array(
            'url' => array_merge(array('action' => 'index'), $this->params['pass'])
            ));

             echo $this->Form->input('creationDateBetween', array(
        'type' => 'date',
        'div' => false,
        'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
        'minYear' => 2013,
        'maxYear' => date('Y'),
        'style' => 'margin-right: 2px; margin-left: 2px',
        'empty' => true,
        'timeFormat' => null,
        'selected' => array(
            'day' => 1,
            'month' => 1,
            'year' => 2013
            ),
        'empty' => false
        ));
         echo $this->Form->input('creationDateBetween2', array(
        'type' => 'date',
        'div' => false,
        'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
        'minYear' => 2013,
        'maxYear' => date('Y'),
        'empty' => true,
        'style' => 'margin-right: 2px; margin-left: 2px',
        'timeFormat' => null,
        'selected' => array(
            'day' => date('D'),
            'month' => date('M'),
            'year' => date('Y')
            ),
        'empty' => false 
        ));
        ?>
<?php

        echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
        echo $this->Form->end();


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way:

In your `Model`

```
public $filterArgs = array(
     'creationDateBetween'       => array(
         'type'      => 'expression',
         'method'    => 'formatStartDate',
         'field' => 'Post.created >= ?'
     ),
     'creationDateBetween2'       => array(
         'type'      => 'expression',
         'method'    => 'formatEndDate',
         'field' => 'Post.created <= ?'
    )
);

public function formatStartDate($data = array())
{
    $date = implode('-', array($data['creationDateBetween']['year'], $data['creationDateBetween']['month'], $data['creationDateBetween']['day']));
    return array($date);
}

public function formatEndDate($data = array())
{
    $date = implode('-', array($data['creationDateBetween2']['year'], $data['creationDateBetween2']['month'], $data['creationDateBetween2']['day']));
    return array($date);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that, It still doesnt seem to be working, cant think what I am doing wrong

Comment: @anilia Sorry it does work of sorts, I will have a better look

Comment: can you please post a `debug($this->data)` in your action? Also: try removing `$presetVars` declaration in your controller